# Modify Log Request Payload in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

How can we modify and log request payload in Spring-boot?

I have already implemented **CommonsRequestLoggingFilter** and am able to log the payload but want to modify the request before being logged so I can hide some sensitive data in the log.

Answer (score 5):

`CommonsRequestLoggingFilter` inherits from `AbstractRequestLoggingFilter` which allows you to supply a predicate that should return `true` in order to log the error.

In my case, I wanted to log all except the authorization header:

```
loggingFilter.setHeaderPredicate(header -> !header.toLowerCase().equals("authorization"));
```

This will result in the logger masking the auth header:

```
... headers=[authorization:"masked", ...]
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.html#setHeaderPredicate-java.util.function.Predicate-